# Accessing nested structures in python

Tags: python

I have a structure `sw_list` formatted as given below

```
 {'ports': [{'hw_addr': 'ee:b1:ab:b1:0e:a0', 'name': 's1-eth1', 'port_no': '00000001', 'dpid': '0000000000000201'}, 
            {'hw_addr': 'f6:83:4d:e4:41:7d', 'name': 's1-eth2', 'port_no': '00000002', 'dpid': '0000000000000201'}
                       ], 'dpid': '0000000000000201'}


for index,switch in enumerate(sw_list):
              dpid_str = dpid_to_str(switch.dp.id)
```

The above loop will print dpid_str which is '0000000000000201' ath the end of the structure.
Now I want to access the contents of ports structure such as

Port 0: hw_addr,name,port_no etc

How do I do that?

Comment: I do not get the question. Can you try to rephrase?

Comment: So `sw_list` is not actually a `list` but rather a `dict`?  Also, what is the dangling `)` at the end supposed to close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d={'ports': [{'hw_addr': 'ee:b1:ab:b1:0e:a0', 'name': 's1-eth1', 'port_no': '00000001', 'dpid': '0000000000000201'},
            {'hw_addr': 'f6:83:4d:e4:41:7d', 'name': 's1-eth2', 'port_no': '00000002', 'dpid': '0000000000000201'}
                       ], 'dpid': '0000000000000201'}

for i in d["ports"][0]:
    print "{} : {}".format(i,d["ports"][0][i])
hw_addr : ee:b1:ab:b1:0e:a0
name : s1-eth1
port_no: 00000001
dpid : 0000000000000201
```